# How do I concatenate the result of two linux commands and have the result on one line?

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, command

I want to run two linux commands such as  :

```
whoami && stat -c %i "/home"
```

But I want the result to be

```
user 123456
```

(all on one line without a break in the line).

Answer (score 1):

Try capturing the results of both of your commands and using something else to format them into a single line.  This should do the trick:

```
echo `whoami` `stat -c %i "/home"`
```

Answer (score 1):

If using bash (or any other shell that supports arrays), you can use an array as well. Simply store the output from your original compound command in an array using command substitution:

```
$ var=( $(whoami && stat -c %i "/home") ); echo "var '${var[@]}'"
var 'david 2'
```

Comment: I just tried that there, and it also works perfectly. Thank You!